# WKWebView Not Loading PDF files after Upgrading to macOs Sonoma

Tags: ios, xcode, networking, wkwebview

Application was showing PDF files before updating to the MacOS Sonoma. After Updating OS it stopped loading PDF's. Application can open images and html content but PDF. I have checked App Sandboxing is turned on with outgoing connections enabled. Also App Transport Security setting are already to the Allow Arbitrary Load to true. Application working normally on iOS and iPAdOs, issue in in MacCatsalyst after MacOs Upgrade to Sonoma

Below is code to add WKWebview on view

```
        let webConfiguration = WKWebViewConfiguration()
        webConfiguration.selectionGranularity = .character
    
        let preferences = WKPreferences()
        preferences.javaScriptEnabled = true
        preferences.javaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically = true
        
        webConfiguration.preferences = preferences
    
    
       self.webView = WKWebView(frame: CGRect.zero, configuration: webConfiguration)
       self.webView.navigationDelegate = self
       self.webView.uiDelegate = self
       self.view.insertSubview(webView, belowSubview: self.progressView)
       let request = NSMutableURLRequest(url: url)
       request.cachePolicy = .reloadIgnoringLocalCacheData
       self.webView.load(request as URLRequest)
```

Not sure what am I missing on any suggestion or suction is most welcome.